# How to respond to duplicate suggestion when I feel no edit is needed?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I have [a question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/304285/1473) that is suggested as a duplicate and says I should edit the question to make it non-duplicative.  If I feel it is not a dup, but I feel the question already, as written, is not a dup, what is the procedure in such as a case?  Do I edit and make a trivial change to touch it?  Or maybe comment on it?  Please advise.

Comment: Make it clear why the suggested duplicate does *not* answer your question. Best to do it by editing your question, though sometimes a clear and well-argued comment is enough. Yes, this does necessarily entail reading, digesting, and internalizing both the other question and all its answers. Note that "*that's a general rule and I don't want to do the thoughtwork of applying it to my specific scenario*" generally does *not* hold water as a defense. The best defense is typically "*here's why that general rule does NOT apply to the scenario I'm asking about, due to these specific details...*".

Comment: There's only one close-to-vote vote so far. Follow Dan's advice and comment to the closer if needed.

Comment: I didn't see it as a duplicate.

Comment: It is a duplicate in a sense that you don't need to hyphenate *shoulder + width*. You quoted the rule and the rule applies to your question. *Shoulder width* is not *unusual* nor *ambiguous* and has only one meaning and is not context-dependent, either.  **The hyphen is . . . used in writing compound words which, without the hyphen, would be ambiguous, hard to read or overly long** is the answer to your question.

Comment: Incidentally I'm having the same problem here: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/304302/105642 No idea what to do, so I am looking forward to an answer.